# Get a GCP project architecture schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture

I've been recently added to a new GCP project which has litterally tons and tons of pods, workloads and bases.
I want to visualize all of it in a schema or model.
Is there any tool or plugin that i can use to modelize the project ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best mechanism would be to use Cloud Console and view the project's resources through the various pages built in to the console.

Google provides very many APIs (services) and these may contain multiple resource (types) and, as you've seen, there can be many instances of the resources.

I think anything that enumerate all a project's resources could be somewhat overwhelming whereas Console provides structure.

Choose your project at or append a query string `project=...` to:

https://console.cloud.google.com